# moviepy: extracting audio from a video and using it in another video

Tags: python, video-processing, moviepy

I'm trying to visually manipulate a video by taking the following steps:

1. Breaking the video into frames (using CV2)
2. Editing each frame (using PIL)
3. Compiling the frames back into a new video (using moviepy)

I'd like to use the audio of the original video in the newly created video.
To do that I first extract the audio from the original video like this:

```
video = VideoFileClip("original_video.mp4") 
video.audio.write_audiofile("audio.mp3")
```

For some reason, the last few seconds of the newly created audio file ("audio.mp3") repeats themselves 2-3 times at the end of the recording. I'm not sure why it happens or how to avoid it.

I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use something besides MP3 (it's 28 years old at this point), does that fix the issue? MP3s have issues with gaps at the beginning and end, and I wouldn't be too surprised if using another format, like AAC or even just WAV, could fix the issue.

Comment: Does the problem related to the 3 steps you are describing above, or is it just related to the two lines of code?

Comment: @Rotem I believe the problem isn't related to the 3 steps but I was hoping describing the macro process might give someone an idea that will make the specific problem redundant.

Comment: @RandomDavis using WAV doesn't solve the problem